# What would be the right approach if my okhttp client is repeating requests on bad connection

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

Right now i am using retrofit 2.0 for rest calls in my android app, and I get duplicates requests when the users have a bad connection. I would like to implement what they suggest  [here](https://medium.com/inloop/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace), but i am not sure about the impacts of doing this, i also checked the documentation [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#retryOnConnectionFailure-boolean-).

The problem that i want to solve: I am generating a ticket number in local because my app works offline & online. If a user had a bad connection, he is going to generate 2 requests with a different ticket number on bad connection.

What would be the impact of using what they recommend in the first link?

Comment: Would be nice if one could understand the question without following external links.

Comment: the question is very neat, duplicate requests on bad connection @Henry

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I added: `retryOnConnectionFailure(false)` to my OkHttpClient.Builder

Example:

```
      val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      httpClient.retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
```

This seemed to help the issue of low connectivity and so many retries.

I found this solution from reading this article - https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace

Hope this helps.